Bulk Insertion in Multiple Tables using Postgres CTEs - Guaranteeing Child Table Ordering
In Postgres, I have these tables:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Usable" (
  buying int4 NOT NULL REFERENCES "Pricing" (id),
  selling int4 NOT NULL REFERENCES "Pricing" (id),
  code text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Pricing" (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  price NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  max_price NUMERIC NOT NULL
);

I have this json input:
[{code: 'some string', buying: {price: 123, max_price: 123}, selling: {...}}, ...]
I am trying to insert in bulk to both tables in a single query (using CTEs, up to 20k entries). I am using jsonb_to_recordset to convert the json to rows. I would just like to ask about two things:

When I insert into Usable, how can I reference the exact id I inserted for Pricing? My worry is that when I bulk insert into Pricing, I might not get the correct order as with the parsed data (e.g., element 150 of the input array corresponds to element 150's Pricing entry).
Does Postgres have some implementations I can use outside CTEs?

Thank you so much in advance!
